# Looking to study botany, some general advice

Tags: botany

I've been doing some hydroponics lately and I've noticed I don't have much insight about how plants really work under the hood, I would like to have the full picture and understand more about it.

My primary interest is to apply botany knowledge on my hydroponics projects, not to get a job/degree. But, I do understand that studying among my peers is a rich experience, reason why I'm considering this kind of training instead of just grabbing a book.

However, I'm not sure how extensive is the study of botany, if I need a degree in X before starting it, etc.

Also a good book is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Soil science, pedology is good for hydroponics knowledge because you learn agriculture history and chemistry, biological and industrial, which sais which chemicals the plants need, what pH does to chemical availability, root physics, micro and macro nutrients... And aquaculture, i.e. keeping fish books teach you about nitrogen cycles, pH, algal and fungal and other blooms, oxygenaton, stagnation, volumes of filters and throughputs, aquarium botanics, I did a pedology course in Uni and i kept fish for a while, and I know a bit of chemistry, although broad based books on hydroponics are cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out Botany classes at nearby community colleges?  You may have trouble finding an evening class, but I'm sure you'll find daytime classes opening up in the January.

If you need to study independently, can I suggest checking out the Tree Care Industry Association's store. [www.tcia.org](http://www.tcia.org)  They have various learning material to read and watch, leading towards a professional arborist certification.

Good luck in your endeavor.